# Лишние пустые строки при выводе текста из массива в файл

Tags: c

При выводе текста из массива в файл, необходимо в нечетных строках исключить все слова длинее чем len(длина заданная пользователем). Проблема в том, что при выводе в файл появляются лишние пустые строки, если нету слов подлежащих исключению(т.е. все слова короче len).

Исходный текст:

> I remember when, I remember, I remember when I lost my mind
>   There was something so pleasant about that place.
>   Even your emotions had an echo
>   In so much space
>   And when you're out there
>   Without care,
>   Yeah, I was out of touch
>   But it wasn't because I didn't know enough
>   I just knew too much

Код программы:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <malloc.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <locale.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 1024 //максимальное число строк в тексте
 #define MAX_NUMBER_OF_SYMBOLS_IN_A_STRING 1024 //максимальное число символов в строке

int TextOutputAndMemoryReallocation(FILE *InitialText, char **text){
int countofstr=0, i=0, len=0;
for (i=0; i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++){
    strcpy(text[i], "\0");
    fgets(text[i], MAX_NUMBER_OF_SYMBOLS_IN_A_STRING, InitialText);
    len = strlen(text[i]);
    realloc(text[i], len*sizeof(char));
    /*если нулевой символ i-ой стоки нулевой байт =>
    конец файла => прекарщение заполнения массива*/
    if (strcmp(&text[i][0],"\0")==0) break;
    countofstr++;
    }
realloc(text, countofstr*sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<countofstr; i++) puts(text[i]);
return(countofstr);
}
void Transformation2(FILE *TransformedText, char **text, char *word, char *marks, int countofstr, int len){
int i;
/*вывод в файл TransformedText.txt лексем,
 короче заданной длины, в нечетных строках;
 четные строки остаются без изменений*/
for (i=0; i<countofstr; i++){
        if (i%2==0) {
    word = strtok(text[i], marks);
        while(word!=NULL){
            if (strlen(word)<len){
                fprintf(TransformedText, "%s ", word);
                }
            word = strtok(NULL, marks);
        }
        }
        else {
              fprintf(TransformedText, "\n");
              fputs(text[i], TransformedText);
        }
}
}

int main(void){
  FILE *TransformedText=fopen("TransformedText.txt", "w"), *InitialText = fopen("InitialText.txt", "r");
int i, countofstr, len;

 text = (char**) malloc(MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS*sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++){
    text [i] = (char*)    malloc(MAX_NUMBER_OF_SYMBOLS_IN_A_STRING*sizeof(char));
countofstr = TextOutputAndMemoryReallocation(InitialText, text);
scanf("%d", &len);
printf("\n");
Transformation2(TransformedText, text, word, marks, countofstr, len);
return 0;
}
```

Вывод в новый файл:

> I remember when I remember I remember when I lost my mind
>   !!!ЛИШНЯЯ СТРОКА!!!
>   There was something so pleasant about that place.
>   Even your emotions had an echo
>   !!!ЛИШНЯЯ СТРОКА!!!
>   In so much space
>   And when you're out there
>   !!!ЛИШНЯЯ СТРОКА!!!
>   Without care,
>   Yeah I was out of touch
>   !!!ЛИШНЯЯ СТРОКА!!!
>   But it wasn't because I didn't know enough
>   I just knew too much

Comment: Вот так конечно делать не стоит `FILE *TransformedText=fopen("TransformedText.txt", "w"), *InitialText = fopen("InitialText.txt", "r");` нужно делать проверку на открытие файлов

Answer (score 2):

Вот этот блок и добавляет вам дополнительный перевод строки

```
else {
  fprintf(TransformedText, "\n");
  fputs(text[i], TransformedText);
}
```

Так как функция `fgets()` если встречает символ новой строки `\n` вносит этот символ в буффер. То есть он уже есть в буффере `text[i]`.

Comment: что интересно в ветке без `if` перевод строки не стоит.

Comment: Если удалить строку fprintf(TransformedText, "\n"); получается следущее: после выполнения цикла while и вывод всех лексем в одну нечетную строку, четная строка выводится вслед за ней, т.е. без перехода на следующую строку. Получается что-то вроде: I just knew too much There was something so pleasant about that place. Хотя перед There должен быть переход на новую строку.

Comment: Если посмотреть Вашу функцию `TextOutputAndMemoryReallocation` то возникает много вопросов ,  Зачем перевыделять память ? Возможно здесь и происходит ошибка заполнения массива.

Comment: Разве не предпочтительнее перераспределить память, чтобы освободить остальную память, которая не понадобилась при заполнении массива?

Comment: Предпочтительней выделить необходимый кусок памяти, а не выделять 1024 строк по 1024 байта.  Но если Вы выделили столько то используйте полностью.

Comment: Нет возможности сразу выделить необходимое кол-во памяти, т.к. текст может быть произвольный => выделено заранее больше, чем может понадобится. После перераспределение памяти, все равно ее пустой не остается.

Comment: Ну можно узнать размер файла и выделить необходимый размер. НО переменая `marks`  не указана но я подозреваю что это `' '` пробел. Ну поэтому перевод строки `\n` функция `strtok()`и зануляется .  При считывании  зануляйте `\n` и тогда при записи везде ставти.

Comment: marks - массив пунктуационных разделитилей *marks=" .,;:?!()« »". Спасибо за совет-попробую.